# How does tiny url work

Tags: asp.net, seo, tinyurl

I have been wondering how tiny url works.

I would like to develop something similar for my site, but as most people, I use GUIDs for ids. When an object is created, should I then generate a 10 character random string to use as public id, or is there a smarter approach?

Example of old url: www.mysite.com/default.aspx?userId={id}

Example of new url: www.mysite.com/pwzd4r9niy

Comment: Be careful not to allow collisions with the "real stuff" on your site!  That would be bad.

Comment: Borealid, what do you mean by collissions with 'real stuff'?

Comment: Here's a [blog](http://ronny.haryan.to/archives/2009/04/07/build-your-own-url-shortening-service/) post about create a URL shortening service. Goes into a lot of detail about how it works.

Comment: Dofs: he means that if you generate a "new url" that is the same as a real page, you're going to run into trouble (imagine if your random string was `index.aspx` for example...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any kind of random string generator or GUID for this. I don't think there is a much smarter approach. (Palantir offers a nice alternative though, hashing the incoming URL. )

The rest is relatively straightforward: Keep a database table with IDs and target URLs; When a request comes in, look up the ID and do a `header` redirect to the target URL.

More discussion in [this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice.html).

There also are redirection services out there now that use words from a dictionary list to build a URL.

Sadly, EvilURL is gone! It used to create "short" URLs like

```
http://evilURL.com/donkey_porn-shotguns/cracking-virus-exploit
```

that was the only URL redirection service *really* worthwhile. :)

And, as a bit of trivia, [`http://to`](http://to./) is the shortest redirection service (and, I think the shortest web URL) known to man.

Comment: @Piskvor awww, perfect! You just have to *love* this: `http://5z8.info/malicious-cookie_d5d2_hateminorities` :)

Comment: Indeed, what's not to like about someone who lives in a pineapple? :D

Answer (score 0):

Just hash the entire string, to a reasonable length.